# Bootstrap Glyphicons not showing on Django production

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, glyphicons

I'm working on Django 1.5 app running on Heroku servers.

Locally I can successfully render Bootstrap Glyphicons, but when deploying my app to Heroku they show just as small empty squares.

I'm also using django-compressor 1.3 to deal with my assets, so my bundled css file looks like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('http://static.myapp.com/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?528782f48380');
  src: url('http://static.myapp.com/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?&528782f48380#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://static.myapp.com/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?528782f48380') format('woff'), url('http://static.myapp.com/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?528782f48380') format('truetype'), url('http://static.myapp.com/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?528782f48380#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And the files glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf and glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff are correctly uploaded to fonts folder on my cdn tree:

```
cdn
 └── bootstrap
     ├── css
     ├── fonts
     └── js
```

I'm sure the static files inclusion is happening correctly (the paths are correct), but could not realize why they are showing just locally and not on production. Also tried to identify encoding problems, but no clue till now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup on heroku and use the fonts filepath like this:
`static/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`